# Desired State Configuration File Resource Fails

Tags: azure, file, dsc

I am trying to use desired state configuration to check whether or not a file exists in a specific location on the virtual machine that the configuration is applied to. The code compiles but when I try to apply it to the VM through Azure it fails and I'm not sure why. All I'm trying to do is make sure the files I'm checking for are there on the VM. Here is my code:

```
Configuration FilesArePresent

{
    Node "ArePresent"
    {

        File "Microsoft .NET Runtime - 5.0.17 (x64).swidtag"
        {
            Ensure = "Present" # Ensure the directory is Present on the target node.
            Type = "File" # The default is File.
            SourcePath = "C:\Program Files\dotnet\swidtag"
            DestinationPath = "C:\Program Files\dotnet\swidtag"
        }
       }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The code compiles but when I try to apply it to the VM through Azure it fails and I'm not sure why.

- *This could be because of the extension provisioning didn't work properly. as we don't have pull server, we need to check the error from the VM itself.*

[image]

- *So here is the location where the VM logs are stored until the provision succeed or VM is up*

  C:WindowsAzureLogsPluginsMicrosoft.Powershell.DSC
- *You can get the error message from that log*

[image]

- *For complete information go through this [document](https://argonsys.com/microsoft-cloud/library/desired-state-configuration-code-how-to-troubleshoot-the-extension/).*